# Including a value but also excluding that value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table: clients

```
client        department  
Mike           1  
mike           2  
mike           3  
joe            1  
joe            2  
bill           1   
mary           2
```

Is it possible to write code that will find a client who is in ONLY department 1 or (department 1 AND 2) but not in any other department?  In this example only joe and bill would be the result.  I've tried when exit/not exist but that only works when I use one department.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT client
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY client
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN department IN (1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*) AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN department = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

The first part of the `HAVING` clause asserts that, for a given client, *only* departments `1` or `2` appear, and the second part assures that department `1` occurs at least once.

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: this would also allow only department 2. can be easily fixed using two conditions.

Comment: This feels like overkill, although I agree it works.  `min` and `max` should be more efficient.

Comment: It is overkill. but using this method is much more versatile and can be maintained relatively easy. it's much more efficient then 'EXCEPT' and  'min' 'max' wont work for other department numbers or more complex conditions.

Comment: thanks everyone.  i had some issues with the other suggestions but this one worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option using `max` and `min`:

```
select client 
from yourtable t
group by client
having min(department) = 1 and 
    max(department) in (1,2)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49aef3/2)

Comment: How would this generalize to handle 'customer in department 37, or customer in department 37 or 47', or some similar range (where there might be valid departments between the numbers cited)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- I originally had `max(department) in (1,2)` but for performance, `<=` should be better.  You do make a good point though.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- Actually, the more that I thought about your comment, in any practical situation, using `<=` probably wouldn't work.  I shouldn't have edited my answer to begin with :/

Answer (score 0):

Data mockup:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (clientName VARCHAR(20), deptId INT);
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES
    ('Mike', 1),
    ('Mike', 2),
    ('Mike', 3),
    ('Joe', 1),
    ('Joe', 2),
    ('Bill', 1),
    ('Mary', 2);
```

Except-approach Solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT clientName
FROM @t
WHERE deptId = 1

EXCEPT

SELECT DISTINCT clientName
FROM @t
WHERE deptId > 2;
```